# Facing problems in Android connectivity with webserver

Tags: android

I have write a post request in android to connect with web server.The server is connected but the data is not showing on weberver.When the code executes the server successfully connects with android but the rows are empty.I have used volley and json to do this.This is my first time connecting android with webserver so can't find what the problem is :

**My Android Code :**

```
private  void  registerUser ()   {

    final String username = editTextUsername . getText() . toString(). trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword . getText()  .toString() .trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail . getText() . toString() . trim() ;

    Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
    params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);``
    params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            REGISTER_URL, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);

}
```

Comment: Well what do the Logs print? Which one?

Comment: I see no rows. Which rows are empty?

Comment: The rows of a table in my database shows empty fields...And the first one log executes

Comment: I asked you what that log printed. You did not tell.

Comment: Sorry for that, But i found the solution I was giving a wrong IP in URL :)